# Need to reverse a repeat region

Tags: firebase, polymer, firebase-polymer

I have a firebase element that is pulling in the last 5 items

```
<firebase-element id="base" location="https://mydb.firebaseio.com/mydata" data="{{items}}" keys="{{keys}}" limit="5" ></firebase-element>
```

That is bound to this repeat region

```
<template repeat="{{id in keys}}">

<x-chat-list id="chatList"  username="{{items[id]['uuid']}}" text="{{items[id]['text']}}" ></x-chat-list>

</template>
```

I simply need to reverse the order of the repeat region.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to observe the array and reverse it (or store the reversed values in another attribute)
Ex :
keysChanged : function() { this.keys.reverse(); }

If the firebase-element sometimes changed the values in the array without triggering the keysChanged function, you can also use the [observe object](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/polymer.html#observeblock)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a custom Polymer expression, e.g.:

```
PolymerExpressions.prototype.revArray = function(a) {
 return a.reverse();
}
```

and pipe your data to it:

```
<template repeat="{{id in keys | revArray}}">
```

Now you can use this anywhere since the expression handler is global.